# Is possible to use ActAs on other binding than ws2007FederationHttpBinding

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wif

I have a web server and an application server. I need to populate "claim identiy" from web server to application server. Both servers are in my control and in same network.

I use `CreateChannelWithIssuedToken` method to populate claims. When I can use `ws2007FederationHttpBinding` and everything works fine.

But is it possible to use net.tcp or net.pipe for this?
I cannot figure how to configure bindings for these two.

Comment: What have you tried? Where is you code? We can't do very much with that sparse information. Also: if it works, why do you need to change it?

Comment: I want to change it because net.tcp has better performance than any http binding. And when I'll always communicate between my own applications I don't see why not use better protocol if it's posible.